# Appassembler `run.as.user.envvar` when running locally

Tags: java, appassembler

I'm using `appassembler` plugin to generate my application structure successfully. Because my application is started from `init.d` script I amended the configuration so the application runs under `serveruser` rather than `root`:

```
<generatorConfigurations>                         
    <generatorConfiguration>                                               
            <property>                            
                <name>run.as.user.envvar</name>   
                <value>serveruser</value> <-- Here the user is set -->         
            </property>                           
        </configuration>                          
    </generatorConfiguration>                     
</generatorConfigurations>
```

This works fine when deployed to server but I want to be able to run the application locally after running `mvn clean package`. And in that case it tries to `su` (switch user) to `serveruser` which doesn't exist on my local machine. Is there any best practice around this?

The ultimate goal is to be able:

1. Build locally and run via the generated scripts
2. Package the same generated project structure deploy it and run from there

Answer (score 1):

My current solution is to provide Maven profile. If `local` profile is set the property is blank and the `run.as.user.envar` is not set so the start script launches under *current* user.

If no profile is set a *default* profile is set and this set the production user so it is not possible to launch it locally but you can launch on server.

Not 100% but works.